# Find those manufacturers of at least two different computers (PC’s or laptops) with speeds of at least 3.0

Tags: mysql

Find those manufacturers of at least two different  computers (PC’s or laptops) with speeds of at least 3.0

select p.maker,p.model from product p where p.model =any ( select model from pc where speed>=3.0 
union all select model from laptop where speed>=3.0 )
group by maker;

I am not able to solve this

Comment: This is definitely a homework question, but from what textbook, I do not recall.

Answer (score 0):

Left joins and the 'having' clause work well here. Also, do you really have a different table for each product category? Try this

```
select 
p.maker,count(*) 
from product p
left join pc on p.model=pc.model
left join laptop on p.model=laptop.model
where coallesce(pc.speed,laptop.speed)>3.0
group by maker
having count(*)>1
```